# What is the preferred way to implement settings in a Ruby on Rails 3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a Rails 3 application that will have user-specific settings (looks, functionality, etc) and I was seeking some simple advice on whats the preferred way of actually implementing settings.

Do you prefer to have a dedicated model for this stuff? Are hashes acceptable to store in a  database field? Do you prefer cookies or sessions over the database? Is an STI object best?

Maybe list some pros or cons to each different method if you can.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i've same situation like you, user specific setting. In my apps i prefer creating a model to store user's configuration i've User model and User_configuration model, where the relationship is one-to-one.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_configuration
end

class UserConfiguration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Or if you prefer using Hash and store it to database is possible to mark your field as serialize

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences, Hash
end
```

you can see it at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

pros:
- so far i've doesn't have any problem, it easy to maintenance

cons:
- request more table in database

May be it could help you thanks.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was seeking. I'm sure its all dependent on the project size as well.

Comment: I've decided to go with the model method. I think ultimately that will be easier to maintain in the long run as the application grows. I've also read that serialization has its limits based on the size of the text field in the database you are storing in it which has the potential to be one other thing to worry about from corrupt data returning.

Overall I believe the performance issues can be mitigated and if worst comes to worst you could off-shore the key/value storage pair to a service to ease load on the database.

Answer (score 3):

If you want some structured solution you can either have a look at:

1. [Configurable Engine](https://github.com/paulca/configurable_engine)
2. or [rails-settings](https://github.com/100hz/rails-settings)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these gems. I may give some of these a try after I've gotten it down myself within rails itself.